# Can't run kotlin in Intellije

Tags: windows, kotlin, intellij-idea, configuration

I am new in **Kotlin**. This is my first project and  I am having problem. I don't understand what to do now. It'll be really helpful for me if anyone can solve this issue. Thanks in advance. Please look at the photo attached

[image]

Comment: Right-click the file that you want to run, then choose Run. You don't have any run confugirations yet and i guess you just pressed the "run" button at the top?

Comment: At a first glance it seems that you have no source folders marked (no source sets defined). I see a `build.gradle.kts` file in the folders, so you are using Gradle to build this project. Share that file as well. Have you generated a new project through the New Project Wizard of IntelliJ? Or in a different way?

Comment: View | Tool Windows | **Gradle** and call [**Reload** action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-projects.html#gradle_refresh_project) to initiate project reload from Gradle for the IDE to set up the project structure correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to kickstart a kotlin-console-application, reference from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-your-first-kotlin-app.html#dd1e8921

1. From the main menu, select File | New | Project.
2. In the left-hand menu, select Kotlin.
3. Give your project a name and select Console Application as Project
   Template. In Project JDK select a JDK (version 8 or later is recommended).
4. New Kotlin project with the Gradle build system with Kotlin DSL. Click Next, then Finish.

If you cannot see a run option, maybe try to build the project once.